# Why is carbon addMinutes doing bad addition

Tags: php, arrays, php-carbon, array-map

In Laravel environment I have a set of times that I am adding minutes to and it is not giving me what I expect.

In the below `array_map` function there is some weird `addMinutes` happening

```
$d = array_map(function ($date) {
    $base = Carbon::parse($date['time']);
    return [
        'start' => $base->addMinutes(150)->toDateTimeString(),
        'end' => $base->addMinutes(190)->toDateTimeString()
    ]
}, $dates);
```

So 150mins is 2hrs30mins, 190mins is 3hrs10mins, so I would assume the following

```
2018-07-05 19.20.00 (+150 mins) -> start = 2018-07-05 21.50
                    (+190 mins) -> end   = 2018-07-05 22.30
```

I am actually getting

```
2018-07-05 19.20.00 (+150 mins) -> start = 2018-07-05 21.30
                    (+190 mins) -> end   = 2018-07-06 00.40
```

Can anyone see the obvious I'm missing here with the Carbon processing ?  I'm quite certain it has to do with Carbon as I restructured the above `array_map` into a `foreach` and same results with the same `addMinutes`.

Edit:

I've just adapted this code for anyone to help diagnose by pasting the below into [phpio](http://phpio.net/tools/carbon)

```
require 'Carbon/Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

$dates[] = ['time' => '2018-07-05 19:20:00'];

$d = array_map(function ($date) {
    $base = Carbon::parse($date['time']);
    return [
        'start' => $base->addMinutes(150)->toDateTimeString(),
        'end' => $base->addMinutes(190)->toDateTimeString()
    ];
}, $dates);

print_r($d);
```

WEIRD - now the start is correct, but end is still incorrect (showing 2018-07-06 01:00:00)

Comment: FYI, using normal DateTime, I didn't encounter this problem: https://3v4l.org/A1qAB . Weeeeird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at this code:

```
return [
    'start' => $base->addMinutes(150)->toDateTimeString(),
    'end' => $base->addMinutes(190)->toDateTimeString()
]
```

In both situations, you're adding to `$base`, so you're adding 150 minutes, then an additional 190 (so a total of 340 minutes). Try using with `->copy()`:

```
return [
    'start' => $base->copy()->addMinutes(150)->toDateTimeString(),
    'end' => $base->copy()->addMinutes(190)->toDateTimeString()
]
```

Using the following code in `phpio`:

```
require 'Carbon/Carbon.php';
use Carbon\Carbon;

$dates[] = ['time' => '2018-07-05 19:20:00'];

$d = array_map(function ($date) {
  $base = Carbon::parse($date['time']);
  return [
    'start' => $base->copy()->addMinutes(150)->toDateTimeString(),
    'end' => $base->copy()->addMinutes(190)->toDateTimeString()
  ];
}, $dates);

print_r($d);
```

Gives me the following:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [start] => 2018-07-05 21:50:00 [end] => 2018-07-05 22:30:00 ) )

Comment: No problem; just a caveat when modifying a `Carbon` date :)

Comment: `->copy()` is a `Carbon` function, burried in the documentation: *"You can also create a copy() of an existing Carbon instance. As expected the date, time and timezone values are all copied to the new instance."* Most examples are found below the section https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-addsub, where all the `addXXX` and `subXXX` methods use `->copy()` prior.